# Spring loads a configuration class with only empty member variables

Tags: java, spring, junit, configuration-files, configurationproperties

I have a Spring web application, and I'm trying to load a YAML configuration file into a Java configuration class. However, my configuration class only contains empty member variables after it is instantiated in my JUnit test. I'm new to Spring and have probably missed something obvious. I built the project with Maven and have a Maven style directory tree.

My configuration Java class:

> src/main/java/com/my/package/config/YAMLConfigDatabase:

```
package com.my.package;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "database")

public class YAMLConfigDatabase {

    private String url;

    private int port;

    private String schema;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    //Getters and setters are all here.

}
```

My configuration YAML file:

> src/main/resources/application.yml

```
server.port: 8090

database:
  url: 'localhost'
  port: 3306
  schema: 'my_schema'
  username: 'webappuser'
  password: 'secretPassword'
```

My JUnit test to check whether I can indeed load the configuration file:

```
package com.my.package;

import com.my.package.config.YAMLConfigDatabase;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {YAMLConfigDatabase.class})
public class YAMLConfigTest {


    private YAMLConfigDatabase config;

    @Autowired
    public void setYAMLConfigDatabase(YAMLConfigDatabase config){
        this.config = config;
    }

    @Test
    public void isYAMLConfigLoaded(){
        System.out.println(this.config);
        System.out.println(this.config.getPassword()); 
        //The above line returns "null", but I would like it to return "secretPassword".
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

I changed my `YAMLConfigDatabase.java` to look like this:

```
package com.my.package.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "database")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.yml") //new line
@Component
public class YAMLConfigDatabase {

    @Value("${url}") //new line
    private String url;

    @Value("${port}") //new line
    private Integer port;

    @Value("${schema}") //new line
    private String schema;

    @Value("${username}") //new line
    private String username;

    @Value("${password}") //new line
    private String password;
}
```

I used Senior Promidor tip to add the @Value annotation to all member variables, and I also had to add the line `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.yml")`. If I skipped the latter step, the arguments inside the @Value annotations were interpreted literally, as I mentioned in a comment.

Comment: you should add `@Value("${value.from.file}")` for each variable of YAMLConfigDatabase class for inject.  [more info](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation)

Comment: Do you have the same yaml config file under test folder?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, should that be necessary? I just tried it. The result is that the argument inside the @Value-annotation is interpreted literally.

`@Value("${url}")
private String url; //This resolves in url = '${url}'

Comment: @mndeveci, no. I just tried adding it, though, and it didn't make any difference. Would you expect this to be necessary?

Comment: @Magnus, no. Usually it reads from main directory and then overrides the same values which is in test folder. It is not overriding all values but the ones with same key. If you don't have it, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I also fight with this a lot (`@ConfigurationProperties`), I tried to test your code with a simple application;

This is a Spring Boot Application with version 2.0.0 (I also tested it with 1.5.14)

application.yml:

```
custom:
  var1: aaa
  var2: bbb
  var3: ccc
```

ConfigClass.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom")
public class ConfigFile {

    private String var1;
    private String var2;
    private String var3;

    public String getVar1() {
        return var1;
    }

    public void setVar1(String var1) {
        this.var1 = var1;
    }

    public String getVar2() {
        return var2;
    }

    public void setVar2(String var2) {
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

    public String getVar3() {
        return var3;
    }

    public void setVar3(String var3) {
        this.var3 = var3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ConfigFile{" +
                "var1='" + var1 + '\'' +
                ", var2='" + var2 + '\'' +
                ", var3='" + var3 + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringBootAppTests {

    @Autowired
    ConfigFile configFile;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        Assert.assertEquals(configFile.getVar1(), "aaa");
        Assert.assertEquals(configFile.getVar2(), "bbb");
        Assert.assertEquals(configFile.getVar3(), "ccc");
    }

}
```

And at the end of test it succeeds all cases.

I am just guessing; maybe you should remove some extra annotations that you added and don't needed anymore.

Comment: I did what you did here, and also added the line @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.yml") above the class declaration. You can see my edited OP.

Comment: If it is not working without `@Value` annotation, I would say there is still problem. Because you can inject any configuration value with `@Value` annotation to any bean class. You don't need `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation at all.

Comment: It worked without `@ConfigurationProperties` as soon as I renamed file from .yml to .yaml